# Undo delete listview/recycleview with realm object

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, adapter, realm

I made a good Adapter for My RecycleView using Place.java provide by google. I setup a drang and drop and swipe to dismiss. 
Using Adapter for recycleview, when user swipe some row this happends:

```
 @Override
public void onItemDismiss(int position) {
    Place place = mList.get(position);
    Realm r = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
    r.beginTransaction();
    mList.remove(position);
    r.commitTransaction();
    notifyItemRemoved(position);
    //mListener.onPlaceDeleted(place,position);
}
```

This cose cause Exception if remove comment in last line.  Last line help me to notify activity a delete-action, so I can show simple Snackbar which   advise user for "xxx place deleted", and it provide simple action inside snackbar to previus state, and store again Realm object. 
I was thinking that mList.remove (this is an ArrayList) will not cause real delete from realm.

I use same adapter, same listener, same architecture for my custom object which is not a Realm object and all works fine.

Comment: Can you post your logcat with the error?

Comment: It might be a good idea to understand how Realm's auto-update works: https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#auto-updating-objects